# Vue.js Как сделать перетаскивание drag and drop содержимого таблицы

Tags: vue.js, drag, drop

Пытаюсь сделать таблицу на  vue.js, в которой можно drag&drop перетаскивать содержимое из ячейки в ячейку.

```
    <div  class="grid">                     
        <div 
            draggable="true"
            v-for="slot of slots"                        
            :key="slot.index"
            :data-index="slot.index"
            @dragstart="drag"
            @dragover.prevent
            @drop.stop="drop"                    
            >
              <span v-if="slot.content">
                {{ slot.content }}
              </span>                        
       </div> 
   </div>    
</template>

<script>   
    export default {
        name: "Storage",
        props: ['id', 'items' ],
        data() {
            return {
                cells: 27,
                currentTarget: '',
                slots: [],
            };
        },

 mounted() {
       for (let i = 0; i < this.cells; i++) {
          this.slots.push({content: null, index: i})
       }
       for (let item of this.items) {
          this.slots[item.y * 3 + item.x].content = item
       }       
 },
 methods: {
        dragStart(item) {
           this.draggedSlot = item;
        },
        dragEnd() {
           this.draggedSlot = null;
        },
            allowDrop(event, slot) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return true;
            },
            drag (cell) {
             console.log(cell.target.dataset.index)
            this.currentTarget = cell.target.dataset.index
            },
            drop (cell) {
                 if (cell.target.dataset.index === undefined) {
                    const parentDiv = cell.target.parentNode
                    console.log(parentDiv.dataset.index)
                    const oldVal = this.slots[this.currentTarget].content
                    const newVal = this.slots[parentDiv.dataset.index].content
                    this.slots[parentDiv.dataset.index].content = oldVal
                    this.slots[this.currentTarget].content = newVal
                 } else {
                    console.log(cell.target.dataset.index)
                    const oldVal = this.slots[this.currentTarget].content        
                    const newVal =  this.slots[cell.target.dataset.index].content     

                    this.slots[cell.target.dataset.index].content = oldVal
                    this.slots[this.currentTarget].content = newVal
                 }
             }
        }
 }
</script>

<style scoped>
    table {
        width: auto;
    }
.grid { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.2vw;
}
.grid > div {
  font-size: 5vw;
  padding: .8em;
  background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Есть готовая таблица, которая реализует перетаскивание.
Console.log показывает, из какой ячейки берем и в какую ячейку кладем
Имеется цикл, который рассчитывает положение содержимого, как я понял.Все работает.

```
for (let item of this.items) {
    this.slots[item.y * 3 + item.x].content = item
}
```

А как в ячейку закинуть content, какой-нибудь  item в пустую ячейку, когда расположение и координаты в ячейке заданы через position_x и position_y, если 
items  представляет собой следующее:

```
items=[
{id:1, position_x: -1, position_y: -1},
{id:2, position_x: 3, position_y: 2}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение, которое работает для одного объекта.

```
<div>
          <table>
            <tr v-for="(row, i) in table">
                <td draggable="true"
                    :key="j"
                    :data-row="i"
                    :data-ceil="i"
                    @drag.start="drag"
                    @dragover.prevent
                    @drop.stop="drop"
                    v-for="(item,  j) in row">
                    <div class='item' v-if="item">
                    <div class='id'>{{item.id}}</div><br>{{item.name}}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</template>
<script>
 import _ from "lodash";
    export default {
        name: "Storage",
        props: [],
        data() {
            return {               
                size: [8, 8],                
                displayed: false,               
                currentTarget: [],
                nextTarget: [],
                currentPosItem: {},                
                 items:  [
                        {
                            id: 4,                           
                            name: "Queen",
                            quantity: 4,
                            position_x: 3,
                            position_y: 2,

                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,                            
                            name: "Queen",
                            quantity: 1,
                            position_x: 0,
                            position_y: 0,                            
                        }

                    ]

            }
        },

        computed: {

            table: function () {
                const map = [];
                for (let x = 0; x < this.size[0]; x++) {
                    map.push(_.fill(Array(this.size[1]), null));
                }
                _.forEach(this.items, (item) => {
                    if (item.position_x !== -1 && item.position_y !== -1)
                        map[item.position_x][item.position_y] = item;                      
                    this.currentPosItem = item;
                    if (item.position_x !== -1 && item.position_y !== -1)
                        map[item.position_x][item.position_y] = this.currentPosItem;
                });
                return map;
            },

        },
        methods: {          

            drag(event) {
                let target = event.target
                let i = target.dataset.row;
                let j = target.dataset.ceil;
                this.currentTarget = [j, i];
               //if (cell.tagName != 'SPAN') return;            
                let td = target.textContext;  
                console.log(td)                
            },
            drop(event) {  
                let target = event.target              
               // console.log(cell);
                let m = target.parentNode.rowIndex;
                let n = target.cellIndex;
                this.nextTarget = [m, n];
                this.currentPosItem.position_x = m;
                this.currentPosItem.position_y = n;
                console.log(this.currentPosItem);
            }
        },
    };
</script>


<style scoped>
    table {
        width: auto;
    }
    td {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

  .id{
    background-color: yellow;
 }
</style>
```